# stop ssl redirect going to home page

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, seo

A site we are working on [site](https://safe.org.nz)requires forcing to https and www removal 
When we make that happen using this .htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://safe.org.nz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

With this enabled, and we access this url 
http://safe.org.nz/admin <= note http://......
It redirects to https://safe.org.nz instead of https://safe.org.nz/admin

Any ideas ? Thanks very much for any tips

Comment: _Something else_ would seem to be doing that. The directives you posted won't redirect `http://safe.org.nz/admin` because the hostname does not start `www.`. If you look at the network traffic you will see a 302 HTTP response code. The directive you posted is a 301. The directives you posted do not "force HTTPS", they simply canonicalise the www subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MrWhite We're looking into that. The setup is a bit convoluted